# Hi everyone! can someone tell me what " if [ $# -ne 1 ]"means in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have been trying to figure out the following line of code as well: 
if [ ! -e $1 ]
thanks

Comment: http://explainshell.com/ is your friend.

Comment: ...also, we want one distinct and non-duplicative question to a question. If this *weren't* closed as duplicate, it could also be closed as overbroad for asking multiple questions at once. Enforcing these rules helps us build a "long-tail" database with the best possible answers for as many unique questions as possible -- if we have different answers for one "question" that asks both A+B, and a second set of answers for another "question" that asks both A+C, then there's no single canonical place someone with only question A can go for the best possible community-reviewed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break it down:

- `$#` is the number of remaining arguments
- `[` is the `test` command
- `-ne` is the numeric "not equals" operator.

So `if [ $# -ne 1 ]` is testing if there is exactly one argument (left).

In your second example:

- `!` means not
- `-e` tests if a file exists
- `$1` is the first remaining argument

Therefore `if [ ! -e $1 ]` tests that there is no file or directory whose path is given as the first (remaining) argument.

Note that this may fail if the argument is a pathname containing whitespace or globing meta-characters.  Quoting is needed to stop word splitting and globbing potentially mangling the pathname; i.e. `if [ ! -e "$1" ]`

Comment: `in "$@"` would be more accurate than `in $*`, as `$*` string-splits and glob expands (changing an argument list of `"first argument" "second argument"` (syntactic vs literal quoting) into `first argument second argument`, or an argument list of `"*"` into a list of files in the current directory).

Comment: Likewise, this explanation ignores the bugs in `[ ! -e $1 ]`, which splits the first argument into a set of words, expands each such word as a glob, and passes each result of that glob as a separate argument to `[`.

Comment: I guess so ......

Comment: thanks for your help!